# Find rows that have the same value on a column perticulat category vise MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database

[image: table : tbl_subcategory]

i want to fetch same SNAME in which cat_id 2 and 4 in where clause.
and in cat_id 1,2,4 there are no same record in SNAME DB field for category 1,2,4 so there is no record found for that
- but in cat_id 2 and 4 ACCESSORIES or few record are same. so it will display in result.

how can i do that ?

Comment: I'm not able to understand properly, exactly what you are looking here. It will be better if you show us expected result/output, that way we can understand what exactly you are looking here.

Comment: i want to fetch ACCESSORIES record from sname  field who have cat_id 2 and 4.

Comment: Normalise your schema.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way  with a inner join n the same table

```
select * from my_table as a
inner join my_table as b on a.sname = b.sname
where a.cat_id = 2 
and b.cat_id = 4;
```

I use the inner join for match the row with same `sname`  ..i select in separated alias table  the rows that match a cat_id .. so in your case i use two alias table (a and b) because you are looking for 2 cat_id (2 and 4)  .. if you need 3 eg 2,3,4 rhe the query is

```
select * from my_table as a
inner join my_table as b on a.sname = b.sname
inner join my_table as c on a.sname = c.sname
where a.cat_id = 2
and b.cat_id = 4
and c.cat_id = 3;
```

Comment: suppose i want to fetch ACCESSORIES record from sname field who have cat_id 2 ,3 and 4. or multiple cat_id then how's do that ?

Comment: This seems a differnet question ..i answered atio your question .. and i think my answer is righte ..   anyway You should use inner join for each cat_id

Comment: exactly my question is that what i ask. but for understand i just explain in simple way.. , if these possible then please give me suggestion friend.!!